# Cannot convert XElement to XObject

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an XML file using the following code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"D:\myfile.xml");
string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc);
```

but it's not working and I am getting following error on 3rd line

> Cannot convert XmlDocument into XObject

I also tried to find the first node and then try to pass it but its also not working.

Comment: Please note that the title you've used doesn't match your actual error. There *is* a conversion from XElement to XObject - but there isn't one from XmlDocument to XObject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `XmlDocument`, which is from the "old" XML API. Json.NET uses the "new" XML API of LINQ to XML. You just need to change how you're loading the XML:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile.xml");
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml);
```